# Information and the difference between Loacal Area Networks and Personal Area Networks

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I've been googling for hours, and I cant seem to find a SIMPLE answer for this question..

I'm doing some research on Local and Personal area networks.

Could someone please explain the difference between the two different types of network, what protocols are used and the good and point the bad of each type. All in language for a NEWBIE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The personal area network is going to refer to very short range connections such as connecting your phone to your computer via usb or bluetooth while local area network (LAN) generally refers to a network of computers in a single organization in a small geographic area. For example if you work at a car dealership, all of the computers in that car dealership are connected together in a local area network. If that car dealership is connected to the internet, this connection would be considered leaving the local area network and connecting to the wide area network (WAN)